# Python Request module error while logging into an Wordpress site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

I am writing a script to download files from a website.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re

with requests.session() as c: #making c denote the requests.session() function
    link="https://gpldl.com/wp-login.php" #login link

    initial=c.get(link) #passing link through .get()
    headers = {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    }
    login_data=    {"log":"****","pwd":"****","redirect_to":"https://gpldl.com/my-gpldl-account/","redirect_to_automatic":1,"rememberme": "forever"} #login data for logging in
    page_int=c.post(link, data=login_data,headers=headers) #posting the login data to the login link
    prefinal_link="https://gpldl.com" #initializing a part of link to be used later
    page=c.get("https://gpldl.com/repository/",headers=headers) #passing the given URL through .get() to be used later
    good_data = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml") #parsing the data from previous statement into lxml from by BS4
    #loop for finding all required links
    for category in good_data.find_all("a",{"class":"dt-btn-m"}):
        inner_link=str(prefinal_link)+str(category.get("href"))
        my_var_2 = requests.get(inner_link)
        good_data_2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(my_var_2.content, "lxml") #parsing each link with lxml
        for each in good_data_2.find_all("tr",{"class":"row-2"}):

            for down_link_pre in each.find_all("td",{"class":"column-4"}): #downloading all files and getting their addresses for to be entered into .csv file
                for down_link in down_link_pre.find_all("a"):
                    link_var=down_link.get("href")
                    file_name=link_var.split('/')[-1]
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(down_link),str(file_name))

            my_var.write("\n")
```

Using my code, when I access the website to download the files, the login keeps failing. Can anyone help me to find what's wrong with my code?
Edit: I think the error is with maintaining the logged in state since, when I try to access one page at a time, I'm able to access the links that can be accessed only when one is logged in. But from that, when I navigate, I think, the bot gets logged out and not able to retrieve the download links and download them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Websites use cookies to check login status in every request** to tell if it's coming from a logged in user or not, and modern browsers (Chrome/Firefox etc.) automatically manage your cookies. **`requests.session()` has support for cookies and it handles cookies by default**, so in your code `with requests.session() as c` c is like the miniature version of a browser, cookie is involved in every request made by `c`, once you log in with `c`, you're able to use `c.get()` to browse all those login-accessible-only pages.

And in your code `urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(down_link),str(file_name))` is used for downloading, **it has no idea of previous login state**, that's why you're not able to download those files.

Instead, you should keep using `c`, which has the login state, to download all those files:

```
with open(str(file_name), 'w') as download:
    response = c.get(down_link)
    download.write(response.content)
```